# Adding a check box (only one can be checked at a time) to my custom list view

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-listview, listadapter

I have made my custom adapter and am adapting an array of "persons". In my list item xml i have put a checkbox, but this is where i get confused. I want my list to only be able to have one check box checked at a time. And i also want to implement an OnCheckBox click listener of some sort to preform an action each time a different check box is selected.

this is my custom adapter

```
 public class PersonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
Person[] mPersonArray;

public PersonAdapter(Context context , Person[] persons) {
    mContext = context;
    mPersonArray = persons;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mPersonArray.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mPersonArray[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;        // we wont use
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        // brand new
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.person_list_item , null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        holder.birthDateText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.birthDateTextView);
        holder.checkBoxList = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Person personForList = mPersonArray[position];

    holder.nameText.setText(personForList.getName());
    holder.birthDateText.setText(personForList.getBirthDate());





    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameText;
    TextView birthDateText;
    CheckBox checkBoxList;
}
```

Here is my list item xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:background="#ff53">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Evan Dix"
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:textColor="#ff323232"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="86dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="11-12-12"
    android:id="@+id/birthDateTextView"
    android:textColor="#ff323232"

    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@android:drawable/presence_invisible"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:choiceMode = "singleChoice"/>
```

And inside my class where i am populating the listview.... it extends ListAdapter

```
 Person[] personArray = new Person[mPersonArrayList.size()];
    personArray = mPersonArrayList.toArray(personArray);

    PersonAdapter adapter = new PersonAdapter(this , personArray);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Use a member variable to store the current selected index, register a listener for each checkbox that updates that index, and use it in `getView` to set current checkbox state.

Comment: I disagree with Visionwriter and cchapman, posted answers below. A row item on ListView has a its own view. They cannot be grouped like RadioButtons or a group of radio buttons.

Comment: However I think you should change the UI design of using checkboxes. Normally users can select many checkbox, more than one. This is the trend and should not deviate.  For suggestion, how about highlight a row item when a user selects it, and only one item can be highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used this in my project and you can also try, but if you have to check one checkbox at one time then why are you using checkbox you have to use radiobutton.

```
 // initialize selectPosition in your base adapter
    int selectedPosition =   -1; 

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                // brand new
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.person_list_item , null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
                holder.birthDateText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.birthDateTextView);
                holder.checkBoxList = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Person personForList = mPersonArray[position];

            holder.nameText.setText(personForList.getName());
            holder.birthDateText.setText(personForList.getBirthDate());
          holder.checkBoxList.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
                 holder.checkBoxList.setTag(position);
        holder.checkBoxList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        selectedPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();

                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });




            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: I did that and it works perfectly Thank you!! so now can you help me with what happens with the next step. in my class which extends ListAdapter

Comment: what do i do here if i would like to log which item has been selected? i tried to implement oncheckchangedlistener ... but i am confused. Is this the right way? thank you    @Surender Kumar

Comment: Sorry for latee, but actually i had no idea about that because i never worked on listadapter.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what your are looking for is a radio button rather than a check box.

Check boxes are made so that you are able to select multiple items of one category, where radio buttons are made so that you are able to only click one of the category.